# React Navigation v3 vs. React Native Navigation v2

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I would like an update about [this previous topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147766/react-navigation-vs-react-native-navigation).
At the time, [react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/) seems to have way better performance than [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/).

How is it with newer version?

For exemple, the use of StackNavigator slows my App besause of the pushing views, I prefer use `this.props.navigation.replace('NewPage')` than `this.props.navigation.navigate('NewPage')` for better performance.

But I heard about react-native-navigation and was wondering if the difference in terms of performance was really relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO, react-navigation better than react-native-navigation. I did have a lot of chances to compare them (long 2 years in RN development). React-navigation now is pretty fast, and if you develop right with redux and etc, you will not see the problems with perfomance. BUT on other side react-native-navigation is more native and it will bring a lot of crashes to your application for sure, because underhood there a lot of native code with native problems. It is easy to mesure by count of issues on github pages.

Comment: Same thought even now :D

Answer (score 4):

For me react-native-navigation is better than react-navigation. And it is not just about performance. If you value native feel in your app, then there is no any other options for you, because RNN have built-in native features that your users will expect from you, like transition animation on back swipe, Peak and POP, or Shared transition (react-navigation have third party package for that, but third party means more issues). Without this stuff, your app will feel hybrid instantly. Not to mention that there is always a possibility that OS manufacturers might implement new native features that will be popular, and your react-navigation app will not be able to support it. Also I have an app with 100K downloads and RNN V2 never caused a crash in production.

For me developing with RNN is more enjoyable. RNN creates a new App Root for any screen or modal or overlay, so it is easy to implement and use components like snackbars or spreadsheets - you don't need insert a components everywhere you want to use it. You just imperatevely call a modal/overlay with navigation api from any part of the app and you don't need to worry about passing a redux method or reference to snackbar or modal.

From my experience with React Native - use native modules instead of JS whenever you can