# What are the differences between react-native-navigation and react-navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

The react native docs are kind of vague when it comes to what makes one better than the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Navigation vs. React Native Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147766/react-navigation-vs-react-native-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

> see the difference about smoothness of the interface, routers , third-party library integration, deep linking and all i preferred react navigation over react native navigation. you can check all the details in this link [check here](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-navigation-vs-react-native-navigation-which-is-right-for-you-3d47c1cd1d63/)